# Google Slides - central master template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

Does anyone know of a way to have a central master template for google slide presentations that automatically cascades changes down to presentations using it ?

If not automatic then maybe there is something that can be done with google apps script to pull any changes to the master template down to the associated presentations ?

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

1. Create master template/theme (M1) with layout (L1) with two placeholders and a company logo
2. Create new presentation (P1) importing theme M1 above using Layout L1
3. Amend master theme M1 Layout A with new company logo or new placeholder

How do i get this change to propagate to P1 without manually importing the template/theme again ? It would be ideal if P1 could subscribe to changes in M1 but i can't see any option for this so was wondering if I could script something ?

Thanks in advance
Greg

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/presentations) would be a helpful resource in seeing what is possible. Would you be able to add in an example of what a master template looks like to you, and what the process of "pull any changes...to associated presentations" looks like. What the start state and end state of that process looks like. Would be happy to help further but the question is a bit vague as it stands.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - I saw that reference but didn't really know how to use it - Have added simple example above

Comment: Having looked into it some, it seems that this is not possible with Apps Script or via the Slides API. Can you provide an example template (M1) and give some context (why you want to do this), as there may be a workaround that can be useful for your use case, though I would need more details and some examples to be able to look into it further, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for you help @iansedano but I don't have any example templates as yet as this is something I was looking into first. I also looked through the APIs and didn't find anything. The reason I wanted to do this was to prevent having to manually update presentations in use that are based on a master template

Answer (score 2):

#### This is not possible in Apps Script right now

There is a feature request for this in the Issue Tracker, go give it a ☆!

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129457735

Maybe go and explain your use case for it too.

#### Possible avenue for workaround

The best workaround I can think of is something along the lines of this script:

```js
function copyStyling() {
  // This is a standalone script
  let masterID = "1107dQEIAbZ8ipBi0wvU6cdy4OV7N2hURT5fjgOwm_vY";
  let childID = "1XvGARRBzXofsjrFJkl8SCmt3tQJ2nkw1n9MG3tr9fhU";

  // Master Slide Variables
  let masterPresentation = SlidesApp.openById(masterID);
  let masterSlide = masterPresentation.getSlides()[0];
  let masterElements = masterSlide.getPageElements();
  
  // Get style elements
  let masterBackground = masterSlide.getBackground();
  let masterSolidFill = masterBackground.getSolidFill().getColor();
  // etc
  // ...
  
  // Child Slide Variables
  let childPresentation = SlidesApp.openById(childID);
  let childSlide = childPresentation.getSlides()[0];
  let childElements = childSlide.getPageElements();
  

  // Updating the stylings for the page
  let childBackground = childSlide.getBackground();
  childBackground.setSolidFill(masterSolidFill);
  // etc
  // ...

  // Updating the stylings for each element on the page
  masterElements.forEach((element, i) => {
    childElements[i].setLeft(element.getLeft());
    childElements[i].setTop(element.getTop());
    // etc
    // ...
  });
}
```

- This script works if both Master and Child presentations use the same theme (i.e. the master style sheets)
- It works by having a single slide in a "Master presentation" which you modify and the Child presentations also have only a single slide.
- It gets style info. This script gets the background of the slide (if its a solid fill) and the top left position of each element.
- It then updates the child with this information.

It really depends on how many changes are going to happen to the child presentations. If no elements are going to change, and only limited style characteristics are going to change, then it shouldn't take too long to get a working script together. It would just involve going through the documentation and picking out the attributes you want to update.

If the number of elements are going to change, their positions going to be rearranged, with very different content from the placeholders, then it can get considerably more complex. Then it becomes a function of how many hours you can invest into it! Though hopefully this serves as a good starting point for that.

Ideally to this script would be added the width and height of each element to go along with the top and left position, their rotation, transformation, font, font color, font font style, direction, and minimal support for shapes. With these things I believe you could have quite a powerful tool.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Slides Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides)

Comment: This is great thanks @iansedano. I have starred the feature request and may add my case for it. Also thanks for the above. I will give it a try :)